# GetComponent returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In both Unity 5.4/5.5, I'm having an issue with GetComponent not returning the CharacterController of my GameObject for some reason. After I restart Unity, it works again.

[image]

_MAIN runs this script:

```
private GameObject frog;
private CharacterController controller;

void Start () {
    frog = GameObject.Find ("Frog");
    controller = frog.GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

    Debug.Log(controller); // returns null
}

void Update () {
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        // error is thrown
    }
}
```

After the `controller` is referenced in Update, I get the error:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'CharacterController' attached to the "Frog" game object,

FYI, `frog` is returning the GameObject just fine.

Comment: Do you have any other GameObject called `Frog` in your scene? Look carefully... Also, please include the complete code of how you are using it in the Update function

Comment: The code stops at `if (controller.isGrounded) {` in Update.

Comment: You can put the update function in your question

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: That' your whole Update function code? controller variable is not being accessed/assigned from another function? Finally, did you import any model from any 3D software?

Comment: Updated code for more clarity. Object is from an FBX. If I restart Unity, everything works. It then randomly brings up the missingexception.

Comment: Instead of using `GameObject.Find("Frog")` try using `GameObject.FindWithTag("Frog")` and add the tag "Frog" to the frog object.

Comment: Adding the tag worked... so why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `GameObject.Find("Frog")` try using `GameObject.FindWithTag("Frog")` and add the tag "Frog" to the frog object.

The reason you are having this happen is somehow, somewhere, a 2nd object named "Frog" is added to the scene. When this happens Unity will randomly pick one of the two objects it found, this will cause it to work sometimes but not other times.

By switching to a tag you make it more likely that the object will be identified uniquely.

Comment: Just like I asked if OP had two GameObjects named "Frog". That was never answered.

Comment: @Programmer considering he responded with `GameObject.FindWithTag("Frog")` fixing the problem in the comments when I asked him about that I think the implied answer to your question is "Yes I do have two things named Frog"

Comment: OP responded with `if (controller.isGrounded) {` on that question but yes, this is the fix for the problem.

Comment: [Here's the rub](http://i.imgur.com/Vfwb9L5.jpg) I do not have another GameObject named `Frog`

Comment: Now it stopped working after I was tweaking params in Animator. There must be something wrong with the FBX file.